# How to get formatted text with entities?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

I need some help with telethon:

I have text from telethon message. Example: `'some text message'`

And i have an entity. Example: `{"_": "MessageEntityBold", "offset": 5, "length": 4}`

I need some method or tip to get formated text like this: `'''some <b>text</b> message'''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Message.text`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.text) returns the text formatted using the current parse mode of the client. By default, this is Telegram's markdown, which means you would get `some **text** message` with the following code:

```
print(message.text)
```

Please note that since it currently relies on the `client.parse_mode`, you cannot use the `.text` property for messages returned by raw API since the results are not modified there. Instead, the message must be fetched with a friendly method or through events.